# Trying to find a specific character of a string in consecutive intervals of 10 using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a data consisted of DNA stored as a sequence of the letters 'a', 'g', 'c' and 't'. In my data I used:

```
count = data.count('t')
print(count)
```

in Python to find that 't' appears 1514710 times.

I want to find how many times 't' appears in consecutive windows of 10 letters as shown below: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYGVH.png)

From the picture, I can tell that 't' appears 3 times in the first interval of 10 (i.e. in the first set of 10 letters 't' appear 3 times out of 10) and 't' appears 2 times in the second set of 10 letters.

I want to show the number for each window without putting a newline after every number in my python script.

So, for instance if my data looks like this:

```
    atgcttgcatgcttgcaaatgcatgcttgcattgcaa
```

I pretty much want my Python output to show something like:

```
    't' appears twice in the first set of 10 letters, 
    and appears 4 times in the second set of 10 letters,
    and so on....
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
    window_size = 10                                                                          
    windows_length = len(data) // window_size                                                
    windows = [data[i:i+windows_length] for i in range(0, len(data),                       windows_length)]        
    result = sum(1 if 't' in (x) else 0 for x in windows)
```

which shows 11

But I am not sure if this is the right way. 
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The question needs more clarity. You can add what you have tried so far and what is your 'data's format? Is it txt or else?

Comment: I agree - I think that information about your data's format and visual example of your desired output will help us to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If dna sequence is a string then there is textwrap.wrap which returns list of  wrapped lines (there can be memory considerations though). So one can write:

```
>>> from textwrap import wrap
>>> dna = 'atgcttgcatgcttgcaaatgcatgcttgcattgcaa'
>>> [chunk.count('t') for chunk in wrap(dna, 10)]
[4, 3, 3, 2]
```

To get chunk numbers enumerate can be used:

```
>>> print(*(f'On row #{i} "t" occured {chunk.count("t")} times' for i, chunk in enumerate(wrap(dna, 10), start=1)), sep='\n')
On row #1 "t" occured 4 times
On row #2 "t" occured 3 times
On row #3 "t" occured 3 times
On row #4 "t" occured 2 times
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break your data into lists of "windows" with list comprehension:

```
windows: List[List[str]] = [data[i * 10:(i + 1) * 10] 
                            for i in range((len(data) + 10 - 1) // 10 )]
```

and then get a count for each window the same way:

```
counts: List[int] = [window.count('t') 
                     for window in windows]
```

You don't specify how exactly you want to print the output so I'll leave the rest for you to determine, but try `print(counts)` to see if that format works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right and you want to count how many windows contain `'t'`. Then my approach would be to split the `data` into `windows` and count how many of them contain `'t'`.

```py
window_size = 10                                                                          
windows_length = len(data) // window_size                                                
windows = [data[i:i+windows_length] for i in range(0, len(data), windows_length)]        
result = sum(1 if 't' in (x) else 0 for x in windows)
```